# How to add a functionality to views bulk operations?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, ubercart, views

I want to use [Views bulk operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) to be able to change all my products' taxonomy terms at once.

I have my product managing view with views bulk operations set up and working but there is no operation for editing taxonomy terms under "Modify entity values".

I assume it is possible to add this functionality, but I'm not sure how, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) comes, out of the box, with some predefined (hardcoded) operations that can be applied to each row selected in the view. The available operations are shown within "Selected bulk operations" when configuring the VBO field. Obviously, something like <kbd>Edit taxonomy terms</kbd> isn't one of them.

However using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) (Conditions and/or Actions) you can execute a [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) operation which you define using a [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) Component. To get the idea, have a look at the video about [Using Rules components with VBO](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/using-rules-components-with-vbo)" uses a Rules Component with (only) 1 parameter. If you want even more, then also watch the subsequent "[Using Rules components with more than one parameter](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/using-rules-componens-with-more-than-one-parameter)" video. This video actually shows how to (also) add a term to a node, so it should be pretty forward to use a similar technique.

For an example in which this technique is used, refer to the answer to "[How to implement the mass operations on the Group's members page using Views?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/220357/how-to-implement-the-mass-operations-on-the-groups-members-page-using-views/220382#220382)".

Note: to process thousands of nodes at once is quite a challenge (memory requirements, etc). Therefor you might want to also watch the video about "[More details about VBO settings](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/more-details-about-vbo-settings)" ... Before you are tempted to use VBO for processing them all at once ...

Happy [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations)-ing while [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)-ing!

Answer (score 0):

You will find an operation called "Modify entity values" in VBO settings. You need to select the field in the Operation settings.

Comment: I know that, I meant what if that operation isnt found in the Operation settings, is there a way to add it?

Answer (score 0):

If the functionality you are looking for is not in there already, you can either write it yourself (as some modules do) following [this guide in the handbook](https://drupal.org/node/459070).

Or you could use the rules module to add this as a component, following this screencast [here](http://nodeone.se/en/using-rules-components-with-vbo).