# How to implement the mass operations on the Group's members page using Views?

Tags: 7, rules, views, group

I use the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module and I want to customize the page to manage the members of the group, created by the module.

So I created a view by following the instructions below :

[How to add a column to the list of group members or create a Views equivalent of it?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/219277/how-to-add-a-column-to-the-list-of-group-members-or-create-a-views-equivalent-of/219776#219776)

How do I do the mass operations of the members page of the module (screenshot 1) on the members page of my view (screenshot 2) ?

[image]

[image]

Here is the export of my view, to manage the members of the groups :

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'group_members';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'group_membership';
$view->human_name = 'Membres';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Membres';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_text'] = 'plus';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'role';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['role'] = array(
  3 => '3',
  9 => '9',
);
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['submit_button'] = 'Appliquer';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['reset_button_label'] = 'Réinitialiser';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['exposed_sorts_label'] = 'Trier par';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'table';
/* Relation: Adhésion au groupe : Groupe gid */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['group']['id'] = 'group';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['group']['table'] = 'group_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['group']['field'] = 'group';
/* Relation: Adhésion au groupe : Utilisateur uid */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['user']['id'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['user']['table'] = 'group_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['user']['field'] = 'user';
/* Champ: Groupe : ID du groupe */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['gid']['id'] = 'gid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['gid']['table'] = 'groups';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['gid']['field'] = 'gid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['gid']['relationship'] = 'group';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['gid']['exclude'] = TRUE;
/* Champ: Utilisateur : Uid */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['id'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['field'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['relationship'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['exclude'] = TRUE;
/* Champ: Groupe : Titre */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'groups';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['relationship'] = 'group';
/* Champ: Utilisateur : Nom */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['relationship'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['label'] = 'Nom d\'utilisateur';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['exclude'] = TRUE;
/* Champ: Global : Texte personnalisé */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_3']['id'] = 'nothing_3';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_3']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_3']['field'] = 'nothing';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_3']['label'] = 'Nom d\'utilisateur';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_3']['alter']['text'] = '[name]';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_3']['alter']['make_link'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_3']['alter']['path'] = 'group/[gid]/member/[uid]';
/* Champ: Utilisateur : Courriel */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['id'] = 'mail';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['field'] = 'mail';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['relationship'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['link_to_user'] = '0';
/* Champ: Adhésion au groupe : Statut de membre */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['status']['table'] = 'group_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['status']['label'] = 'Statut';
/* Champ: Adhésion au groupe : Group role */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['role']['id'] = 'role';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['role']['table'] = 'group_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['role']['field'] = 'role';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['role']['label'] = 'Rôles';
/* Champ: Global : Texte personnalisé */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['id'] = 'nothing';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['field'] = 'nothing';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['label'] = 'Modifier';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['alter']['text'] = 'modifier';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['alter']['make_link'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['alter']['path'] = 'group/[gid]/member/[uid]/edit?destination=group/[gid]/member';
/* Champ: Global : Texte personnalisé */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_1']['id'] = 'nothing_1';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_1']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_1']['field'] = 'nothing';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_1']['label'] = 'Annuler';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_1']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_1']['alter']['text'] = 'annuler';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_1']['alter']['make_link'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_1']['alter']['path'] = 'group/[gid]/member/[uid]/cancel?destination=group/[gid]/member';
/* Champ: Global : Texte personnalisé */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_2']['id'] = 'nothing_2';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_2']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_2']['field'] = 'nothing';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_2']['label'] = 'Metadata';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_2']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_2']['alter']['text'] = 'metadata';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_2']['alter']['make_link'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_2']['alter']['path'] = 'group/[gid]/member/[uid]/metadata';
/* Champ: Global : Texte personnalisé */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_4']['id'] = 'nothing_4';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_4']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_4']['field'] = 'nothing';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_4']['label'] = 'Actions';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_4']['alter']['text'] = '[nothing]   [nothing_1]   [nothing_2]';
/* Critère de filtrage: Adhésion au groupe : Statut de membre */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'group_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'status_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['label'] = 'Membership status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = 'status_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['identifier'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['remember_roles'] = array(
  2 => '2',
  1 => 0,
  3 => 0,
  4 => 0,
  5 => 0,
  6 => 0,
);

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'group/%/member';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['type'] = 'tab';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['title'] = 'Membres';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['weight'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context_only_inline'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['tab_options']['weight'] = '0';
$translatables['group_members'] = array(
  t('Master'),
  t('Membres'),
  t('plus'),
  t('Appliquer'),
  t('Réinitialiser'),
  t('Trier par'),
  t('Asc'),
  t('Desc'),
  t('Groupe'),
  t('Utilisateur'),
  t('ID du groupe'),
  t('.'),
  t(','),
  t('Uid'),
  t('Titre'),
  t('Nom d\'utilisateur'),
  t('[name]'),
  t('Courriel'),
  t('Statut'),
  t('Rôles'),
  t('Modifier'),
  t('modifier'),
  t('Annuler'),
  t('annuler'),
  t('Metadata'),
  t('metadata'),
  t('Actions'),
  t('[nothing]   [nothing_1]   [nothing_2]'),
  t('Membership status'),
  t('Page'),
);
```

**Update**:

I imported the Rules Component as included in [revision 1](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/revisions/220382/1) of Pierre's answer and I created a field "Mass Operations: Group Membership (Group Membership)". But I can not find that Rules Component in the view.

[image]

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'group_members';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'group_membership';
$view->human_name = 'Membres';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Membres';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_text'] = 'plus';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'role';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['role'] = array(
  3 => '3',
  9 => '9',
);
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['submit_button'] = 'Appliquer';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['reset_button_label'] = 'Réinitialiser';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['exposed_sorts_label'] = 'Trier par';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'table';
/* Relation: Adhésion au groupe : Groupe gid */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['group']['id'] = 'group';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['group']['table'] = 'group_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['group']['field'] = 'group';
/* Relation: Adhésion au groupe : Utilisateur uid */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['user']['id'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['user']['table'] = 'group_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['user']['field'] = 'user';
/* Champ: Opérations en masse : Adhésion au groupe */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['id'] = 'views_bulk_operations';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['table'] = 'group_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['field'] = 'views_bulk_operations';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['display_type'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['enable_select_all_pages'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['row_clickable'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['force_single'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['entity_load_capacity'] = '10';
/* Champ: Groupe : ID du groupe */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['gid']['id'] = 'gid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['gid']['table'] = 'groups';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['gid']['field'] = 'gid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['gid']['relationship'] = 'group';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['gid']['exclude'] = TRUE;
/* Champ: Utilisateur : Uid */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['id'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['field'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['relationship'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['exclude'] = TRUE;
/* Champ: Groupe : Titre */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'groups';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['relationship'] = 'group';
/* Champ: Utilisateur : Nom */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['relationship'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['label'] = 'Nom d\'utilisateur';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['exclude'] = TRUE;
/* Champ: Global : Texte personnalisé */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_3']['id'] = 'nothing_3';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_3']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_3']['field'] = 'nothing';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_3']['label'] = 'Nom d\'utilisateur';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_3']['alter']['text'] = '[name]';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_3']['alter']['make_link'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_3']['alter']['path'] = 'group/[gid]/member/[uid]';
/* Champ: Utilisateur : Courriel */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['id'] = 'mail';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['field'] = 'mail';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['relationship'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['link_to_user'] = '0';
/* Champ: Adhésion au groupe : Statut de membre */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['status']['table'] = 'group_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['status']['label'] = 'Statut';
/* Champ: Adhésion au groupe : Group role */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['role']['id'] = 'role';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['role']['table'] = 'group_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['role']['field'] = 'role';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['role']['label'] = 'Rôles';
/* Champ: Global : Texte personnalisé */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['id'] = 'nothing';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['field'] = 'nothing';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['label'] = 'Modifier';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['alter']['text'] = 'modifier';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['alter']['make_link'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['alter']['path'] = 'group/[gid]/member/[uid]/edit?destination=group/[gid]/member';
/* Champ: Global : Texte personnalisé */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_1']['id'] = 'nothing_1';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_1']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_1']['field'] = 'nothing';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_1']['label'] = 'Annuler';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_1']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_1']['alter']['text'] = 'annuler';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_1']['alter']['make_link'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_1']['alter']['path'] = 'group/[gid]/member/[uid]/cancel?destination=group/[gid]/member';
/* Champ: Global : Texte personnalisé */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_2']['id'] = 'nothing_2';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_2']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_2']['field'] = 'nothing';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_2']['label'] = 'Metadata';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_2']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_2']['alter']['text'] = 'metadata';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_2']['alter']['make_link'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_2']['alter']['path'] = 'group/[gid]/member/[uid]/metadata';
/* Champ: Global : Texte personnalisé */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_4']['id'] = 'nothing_4';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_4']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_4']['field'] = 'nothing';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_4']['label'] = 'Actions';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_4']['alter']['text'] = '[nothing]   [nothing_1]   [nothing_2]';
/* Critère de filtrage: Adhésion au groupe : Statut de membre */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'group_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'status_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['label'] = 'Membership status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = 'status_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['identifier'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['remember_roles'] = array(
  2 => '2',
  1 => 0,
  3 => 0,
  4 => 0,
  5 => 0,
  6 => 0,
);

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'group/%/member';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['type'] = 'tab';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['title'] = 'Membres';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['weight'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context_only_inline'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['tab_options']['weight'] = '0';
$translatables['group_members'] = array(
  t('Master'),
  t('Membres'),
  t('plus'),
  t('Appliquer'),
  t('Réinitialiser'),
  t('Trier par'),
  t('Asc'),
  t('Desc'),
  t('Groupe'),
  t('Utilisateur'),
  t('Adhésion au groupe'),
  t('- Choisir une opération -'),
  t('ID du groupe'),
  t('.'),
  t(','),
  t('Uid'),
  t('Titre'),
  t('Nom d\'utilisateur'),
  t('[name]'),
  t('Courriel'),
  t('Statut'),
  t('Rôles'),
  t('Modifier'),
  t('modifier'),
  t('Annuler'),
  t('annuler'),
  t('Metadata'),
  t('metadata'),
  t('Actions'),
  t('[nothing]   [nothing_1]   [nothing_2]'),
  t('Membership status'),
  t('Page'),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to transform the view you already have into a view that uses [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations), and use the technique documented in "[How to use Rules to create a custom bulk operation for a VBO view?](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/88)".

In doing so, you'll then be able to use Rules Components (using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module), in which you can then include the required logic to perform the equivalent of each of the mass operations of the Group members page.

Below is an example to explain the key concept of the solution. It includes everything (= 2 Rules Components + a VBO views) you need to implement the equivalent of these openrations that are available on `group/gid/member`:

- Block selected members.
- Unblock selected members.

#### Part 1 - Rules Component to Block selected members

Here is the rule (in Rules export format which you can import if you have the Rules UI enabled), which you can use in your VBO enabled view to perform the equivalent of "Block selected members"):

```
{ "rules_block_a_group_membership" : {
    "LABEL" : "Block a group membership",
    "PLUGIN" : "rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "USES VARIABLES" : { "group_mbrship" : { "label" : "Group membership", "type" : "group_membership" } },
    "IF" : [
      { "NOT data_is" : { "data" : [ "group-mbrship:status" ], "value" : "blocked" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "group-mbrship:status" ], "value" : "blocked" } },
      { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "Membership status for group \u0022[group-mbrship:group]\u0022 updated to BLOCKED for user \u0022[group-mbrship:user]\u0022." } }
    ]
  }
}
```

#### Part 2 - Rules Component to Unblock selected members

Here is the rule (in Rules export format which you can import if you have the Rules UI enabled), which you can use in your VBO enabled view to perform the equivalent of "Unblock selected members"):

```
{ "rules_unblock_a_group_membership" : {
    "LABEL" : "Unblock a group membership",
    "PLUGIN" : "rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "USES VARIABLES" : { "group_mbrship" : { "label" : "Group membership", "type" : "group_membership" } },
    "IF" : [
      { "NOT data_is" : { "data" : [ "group-mbrship:status" ], "value" : "active" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "group-mbrship:status" ], "value" : "active" } },
      { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "Membership status for group \u0022[group-mbrship:group]\u0022 changed to ACTIVE for user \u0022[group-mbrship:user]]\u0022." } }
    ]
  }
}
```

#### Part 3 - VBO view that uses both Rules Components

Here is the VBO view (in Views export format) that refers (uses) the 2 Rules Components from above:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'group_members';
$view->description = 'List of all members in a specific Group';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'group_membership';
$view->human_name = 'Group Members';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Membres';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_text'] = 'plus';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'role';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['role'] = array(
  3 => '3',
);
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['submit_button'] = 'Appliquer';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['reset_button_label'] = 'Réinitialiser';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['exposed_sorts_label'] = 'Trier par';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'table';
/* Relationship: Group membership: Group gid */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['group']['id'] = 'group';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['group']['table'] = 'group_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['group']['field'] = 'group';
/* Relationship: Group membership: User uid */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['user']['id'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['user']['table'] = 'group_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['user']['field'] = 'user';
/* Field: Bulk operations: Group membership */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['id'] = 'views_bulk_operations';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['table'] = 'group_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['field'] = 'views_bulk_operations';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['display_type'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['enable_select_all_pages'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['row_clickable'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['force_single'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['entity_load_capacity'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_operations'] = array(
  'rules_component::rules_block_a_group_membership' => array(
    'selected' => 1,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
  'rules_component::rules_unblock_a_group_membership' => array(
    'selected' => 1,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
);
/* Field: Group: Group ID */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['gid']['id'] = 'gid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['gid']['table'] = 'groups';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['gid']['field'] = 'gid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['gid']['relationship'] = 'group';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['gid']['exclude'] = TRUE;
/* Field: User: Uid */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['id'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['field'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['relationship'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['exclude'] = TRUE;
/* Field: Group: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'groups';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['relationship'] = 'group';
/* Field: User: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['relationship'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['label'] = 'Nom d\'utilisateur';
/* Field: User: E-mail */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['id'] = 'mail';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['field'] = 'mail';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['relationship'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mail']['link_to_user'] = '0';
/* Field: Group membership: Membership status */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['status']['table'] = 'group_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['status']['field'] = 'status';
/* Field: Group membership: Group role */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['role']['id'] = 'role';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['role']['table'] = 'group_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['role']['field'] = 'role';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['role']['label'] = 'Rôles';
/* Field: Global: Custom text */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_3']['id'] = 'nothing_3';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_3']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_3']['field'] = 'nothing';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_3']['label'] = 'View';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_3']['alter']['text'] = 'view';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_3']['alter']['make_link'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_3']['alter']['path'] = 'group/[gid]/member/[uid]';
/* Field: Global: Custom text */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['id'] = 'nothing';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['field'] = 'nothing';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['label'] = 'Modifier';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['alter']['text'] = 'modifier';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['alter']['make_link'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['alter']['path'] = 'group/[gid]/member/[uid]/edit?destination=group/[gid]/member';
/* Field: Global: Custom text */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_1']['id'] = 'nothing_1';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_1']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_1']['field'] = 'nothing';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_1']['label'] = 'Annuler';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_1']['alter']['text'] = 'annuler';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_1']['alter']['make_link'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_1']['alter']['path'] = 'group/[gid]/member/[uid]/cancel?destination=group/[gid]/member';
/* Field: Global: Custom text */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_2']['id'] = 'nothing_2';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_2']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_2']['field'] = 'nothing';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_2']['label'] = 'Metadata';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_2']['alter']['text'] = 'metadata';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_2']['alter']['make_link'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_2']['alter']['path'] = 'group/[gid]/member/[uid]/metadata';
/* Contextual filter: Group: Group ID */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['gid']['id'] = 'gid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['gid']['table'] = 'groups';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['gid']['field'] = 'gid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['gid']['relationship'] = 'group';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['gid']['title_enable'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['gid']['title'] = 'Members of the group with Group Id = %1';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['gid']['default_argument_type'] = 'fixed';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['gid']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['gid']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['gid']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['gid']['specify_validation'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['gid']['validate']['type'] = 'numeric';
/* Filter criterion: Group membership: Membership status */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'group_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'status_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['label'] = 'Membership status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = 'status_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['identifier'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['remember_roles'] = array(
  2 => '2',
  1 => 0,
  3 => 0,
  4 => 0,
  5 => 0,
  6 => 0,
);

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'group/%/memberlist';
```

#### Bonus feature

Since using `all` in the path `group/all/memberlist` is also supported in this VBO view, with this solution you can block/unblock memberships in a single mass operation for multiple groups at once (which you cannot do with what's delivered with the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module ...).

#### Not all Rules Components can be selected

Even though you may think "hm, is it really that easy?", it happens that after you created a Rules Component and try to use it in a VBO view, that Rules Component cannot be selected as an operation to be enabled in your [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) view.

As an example, here is a variation of the above rules (in Rules export format which you can import if you have the Rules UI enabled), which also performs the equivalent of "Block a member"):

```
{ "rules_group_membership_block_a_member" : {
    "LABEL" : "Group membership - block a member",
    "PLUGIN" : "rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "USES VARIABLES" : {
      "group_user" : { "label" : "Group User", "type" : "user" },
      "group_mbrship" : { "label" : "Group mbrship", "type" : "group_membership" }
    },
    "DO" : [
      { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "group-mbrship:status" ], "value" : "blocked" } },
      { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "Membership status for group \u0022[group-mbrship:group]\u0022 changed to BLOCKED for user \u0022[group-user:name]\u0022." } }
    ]
  }
}
```

However you won't be able to select this Rules Component ... If you wonder why, or wonder what it would take to make it show up anyway (in the VBO view), then use [this link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) ...

Comment: Thank you the 2 components (Part1 and Part2) works very well and the view works. I tried all the afternoon to create the components (Delete Selected Members, Add Role to Selected Members, Delete Role of Selected Members), but none of them work. In actions, should "Define a data value" as for the previous components ? I tested several values but none worked.

Comment: @Mathieu: merci for the feedback/comment/accept/confirmation. Sorry to hear that "the solution to the problem, changes the problem". I haven't experimented/tried "yet" to create another Rules Component to also implement any of the other mass update actions (eg those you cannot get to work), but I'd be happy to soon do some experiments about some of those also (maybe tomorrow?). How about you post yet another followup question about that already, something like "As a followup to my previous question, how should the Rules component look like for 'Add role to Selected Members?".

Comment: Hello, I have created a new question, but I do not understand why it is necessary to create a new question when it is almost identical http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/220633/how-do-i-create-components-based-on-the-group-module

Comment: @Mathieu : merci for that new question. It is needed to avoid what is called "chameleon" questions (= after a question is answered, the question is changed, expanded, etc, which potentially invalidates 1 or more answers). Moreover, it helps to keep question "understandable", and limited in scope. And don't forget: posting a new question is FREE of charge (you may even "earn" rep-points via votes, accept of answer, etc). OK? BTW: you new question could actually have been 3 separated questions ...