# How to correct my Rules Components to perform VBO operations to add or remove a role for the Group module?

Tags: 7, rules, views, group

I followed the instructions included in the answer to the question "[How to implement the mass operations on the Group's members page using Views?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/220357/how-to-implement-the-mass-operations-on-the-groups-members-page-using-views/220382#220382)". The 2 Rules Components in it (to either block or unblock a member), work fine (and my VBO view shows the mass operations that use those 2 Rules Components).

Now I want to create similar Rules Components for some of the other typical mass update operations, related to members and/or roles (as used in the context of the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module).

Below are the 2 Rules Components (in Rules export format) I created for this so far:

#### 1. Add a role to the selected members:

```
{ "rules_add_role_a_group_membership" : {
    "LABEL" : "Add role a group membership",
    "PLUGIN" : "rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "USES VARIABLES" : { "group_mbrship" : { "label" : "Group membership", "type" : "group_membership" } },
    "IF" : [
      { "NOT data_is" : {
          "data" : [ "group-mbrship:roles" ],
          "value" : { "value" : { "group_admin" : "group_admin" } }
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "data_set" : {
          "data" : [ "group-mbrship:roles" ],
          "value" : { "value" : { "group_admin" : "group_admin" } }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This Rules Component should implement the equivalent of the *Update option* "***Add role to selected members***" (as shown on `group/gid/member`, with `gid`=group id).

#### 2. Delete the role of the selected members:

```
{ "rules_remove_role_a_group_membership" : {
    "LABEL" : "Remove role a group membership",
    "PLUGIN" : "rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "USES VARIABLES" : { "group_mbrship" : { "label" : "Group membership", "type" : "group_membership" } },
    "IF" : [
      { "data_is" : {
          "data" : [ "group-mbrship:roles" ],
          "value" : { "value" : { "group_admin" : "group_admin" } }
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "group-mbrship:roles" ], "value" : { "value" : [] } } }
    ]
  }
}
```

This Rules Component should implement the equivalent of the *Update option* "***Remove role from selected members***" (as shown on `group/gid/member`, with `gid`=group id).

**When I add or remove a role, the following error displays :**

[image]

I have a problem with the confirmation of action display :

[image]

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I can not rectify the error. Are my components correct? Thank you

Comment: Bonjour Mathieu! No they are **NOT** correct, I think. Because what you're trying to do, is to add (or remove) a role from a ***list of roles***. And that (for 'add') needs to be done with "Add an item to a list", and not "Set a data value". I have made a little progress to fabricate an appropriate Rules Component, but still "something" still causes some bizarre error (which I don't understand). And I start to wonder if it is even possible to combine such Rules Component with a VBO-view about "memberships". Did you notice there is 1 VBO action for each ROLE to add, or to delete? Why is that?

Comment: Hey Mathieu, about your last comment: even though you only use 1 role, the type of the field(s) where that role is to be added is still a list. So therefor it can also never work with "Set a data value". So I'm pretty sure it has to be done with "Add an item to a list". FYI: more feedback (maybe an answer?) when I made relevant progress to get it to work ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens 
Thanks for the information I updated the components. Everything happens correctly but the role is not applied. I encounter another problem (see the last screenshot in the question), indeed the confirmation message seems to be in plain text.

Comment: Aha, about your "*Everything happens correctly but the role is not applied*": that's ***exactly*** how far I am myself in my own setup/experiments (= it does not cause any error or produce any msg, but if I then check the user's role nothing seem to have happened ...grrrrrrrr). Which is why I've now started to look for some other type of "entity" (instead of group membership) that needs to be created via the Rules Component. My best guess for now is something related to the "Group Role" for now. I will need more time for more experiments about all this, so sorry "for now" ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I think you do not have a question. In the last screenshot of the question, the confirmation message displays the html tags. How do I view this message correctly ? All the confirmation messages for my components are displayed as plain text !

Comment: Mathieu, [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2830083) is my current status ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens https://www.drupal.org/node/2508990